# RecyclerView add icon on right swipe

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've added the touchCallback to my RecyclerView and i was adding a background color when the item is swiped with a relative icon.

The issue is that I achieved the positioning of the icon on left swipe, but i can't set it correctly when the item is swiped to right.

I just can see the icon partially while i would it to be shown as in the left swipe..

Actually all looks like this:[image]

And my touchCallback function is the following:

```
private fun initSwipe(recycler: RecyclerView) {
    val simpleItemTouchCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        private val clearPaint = Paint().apply { xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR) }
        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition

            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

                Toast.makeText(activity, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                recycler.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position)
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(activity, position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                recycler.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position)
            }


        }

        override fun onChildDraw(
            c: Canvas,
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            dX: Float,
            dY: Float,
            actionState: Int,
            isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
        ) {
            val background = ColorDrawable()
            val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
            val itemHeight = itemView.bottom - itemView.top
            val isCanceled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive

            if (isCanceled) {
                clearCanvas(c, itemView.right + dX, itemView.top.toFloat(), itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                return
            }

            if (dX > 0) {
                val editIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_edit)
                val intrinsicWidth = editIcon?.intrinsicWidth
                val intrinsicHeigh = editIcon?.intrinsicHeight
                // Draw the green background
                val backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#32a852")
                background.color = backgroundColor
                background.setBounds(itemView.left, itemView.top, dX.toInt() + 10, itemView.bottom)
                background.draw(c)

                // Calculate position of delete icon
                val deleteIconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeigh!!) / 2
                val deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeigh) / 2
                val deleteIconLeft = itemView.left - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth!!
                val deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeigh

                // Draw the delete icon
                editIcon.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconMargin, deleteIconBottom)
                editIcon.draw(c)
            }else {
                val deleteIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_delete)
                val intrinsicWidth = deleteIcon?.intrinsicWidth
                val intrinsicHeigh = deleteIcon?.intrinsicHeight
                // Draw the delete background
                val backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#f44336")
                background.color = backgroundColor
                background.setBounds(itemView.right + dX.toInt(), itemView.top, itemView.right, itemView.bottom)
                background.draw(c)

                // Calculate position of delete icon
                val deleteIconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeigh!!) / 2
                val deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeigh) / 2
                val deleteIconLeft = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth!!
                val deleteIconRight = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin
                val deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeigh

                // Draw the delete icon
                deleteIcon.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom)
                deleteIcon.draw(c)
            }

            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
        }


        private fun clearCanvas(c: Canvas?, left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
            c?.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, clearPaint)
        }
    }


    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left side of the icon should be at the left edge of the view plus the margin size:

```
val deleteIconLeft = itemView.left + deleteIconMargin
```

You didn't calculate a right side. The right side should be the left side plus the width:

```
val deleteIconRight = deleteIconLeft + instrinsicWidth!!
```

And then you need to use the right side, not the margin, when setting bounds:

```
editIcon.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom)
```

Comment: it looks "a bit" stretched here a [photo](https://i.gyazo.com/b162ee52d770f1bd1831e2711dabae68.png)

Comment: Oops. I didn't look at the rest of your code. Just saw the out-of-place minus signs. I updated with a more complete review of it.

Comment: played with that values couple of times but never tryed to set the `iconRight = iconLeft + instrinsicWidth!!`

Answer (score 2):

I created a library for that exact usage, it adds the icons and optionally texts too, in both swiping directions. You can add it to your `build.gradle`. Here's the link to the documentation: https://github.com/kevingermainbusiness/ItemDecorator

[image][image]

Comment: how use it in java

Comment: @ElfnanSherif You just add the library to your build.gradle file, sync it, & then follow the guidelines on how to call the library in your code the same way in java. All info about how the library can be used is available at this address: https://github.com/kevingermainbusiness/ItemDecorator.